# why must I sleep or wait using watir-webdriver and firefox?

Tags: firefox, watir, webdriver, watir-webdriver

Well i wanted to comment on watir-webdriver wait for page load>this topic but since i have 1 rep I cannot.

I'm upgrading my watir scripts to watir-webdriver and the first test i ran on Firefox yielded:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"body"}
```

when all I was doing was logging into my app (which worked fine), clicking the Build Info link, and doing a:

```
@browser.text
```

This happened consistently.  After reading on here, I put a sleep after the click and before the @browser.text and it worked.  My conclusion is obviously that the Firefox driver is not waiting until the page is loaded before trying the

```
-> POST session/8607aaa2-d72d-448a-85e1-3f96a1766da1/element
{"value":"body","using":"tag name"}
```

So my question is is this an isolated incident (calling @browser.body, which is not an entirely typical call) or am I going to have to use waits?  It seems the whole beauty of watir is lost if I cannot expect the driver to wait until the browser is in a ready state.  Also, is there a dev google group or something like that for watir-webdriver?  I have the feeling I'm going to see more and more issues (several with IE9).  I'll probably also ask on Alister's blog (which rocks, btw).

Comment: what version of watir-webdriver and selenium-webdriver gems are you using?

Comment: I would try to install selenium-webdriver 2.4.0 and see if you have the same problem

Comment: should have included that info: ruby 1.8.7 p352, selenium-webdriver (2.5.0) watir (2.0.1) watir-webdriver (0.3.3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Watir-WebDriver should wait until a page is ready, but the problem is so much content is dynamically generated, there really isn't a every a clear definition of ready.

This is where the waiting helper methods shine: http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/

Find an element you know you expect, and use something like:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.start 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
b.select_list(:id => 'entry_1').wait_until_present
```

**Update:**

I think your problem is native events related. Try disabling native events

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.native_events = false
b = Watir::Browser.new WEB_DRIVER, :profile => profile
```

Comment: Our app uses plenty of ajax, and it's often (painfully) clear that some content is asynchronously arriving at the client.  I have taken that into account since using watir 1.6.2, but in this example I'm 95% sure that the content is static.  I would hate to have to add waits everywhere (it was the reason I chose watir over sel years ago), but to avoid that i'll have to add them at my "watir wrapper" layer, and it seems if this is the appropriate strategy, then selenium devs would have built-in wait_until_present for every object that was ever accessed...

Comment: try disabling native events. it fixed things for me

Comment: well luckily i already had a WatirUtil layer that wraps all my watir calls, so i basically just modified it and am now wrapping everything in a rescue block that tries for N seconds to click, set, clear, etc.  I really hate this.  If I hadn't had this layer already implemented I would just not be able to use WW and would have to go back to watir, which worked perfectly 99.9% of the time.  I appreciate the native events comment but per your blog i'd already set that...

Comment: I just found that using selenium::webdriver you can create/increase the implicit wait.  This would be a nice thing to have for watir-webdriver:     driver.manage.timeouts.implicitlyWait(90);

Comment: You can use the same method in watir-webdriver as we speak: browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 20

Comment: Thank You @alister!  I swear I looked through browser.driver.manage.timeouts.methods but I must not have.  Thank you!  I feel like this should be painfully clearly documented and/or a method of Browser.  I believe this is the best solution I've come across to waiting.