# Inconsistence Execution of Watir-Web Driver?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I've written a ruby script to test my application. Sometimes it seems to be executing without any error. When executing the same code next time however, the execution is not working as expected and it throws an error. Why it is behaving like this?

The error:

```
[remote server] file:///C:/Users/RAGHUN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20140818-5504-b2tdgg/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_componen
t.js:9470:133:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_': Unable to locat
e element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"body"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::
NoSuchElementError)
```

Also to overcome this issue tried `Watir::always_locate = true` but this is also not working. Am I missing any gem files? Can any one provide a suggestion?

Comment: It looks like there was a [similar question before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7424645/1200545). Maybe give those solutions a try?

Comment: @JustinKo - Thanks for your response ..Gone through the discussion and executed the code now getting error as `<main>': uninitialized constant WEB_DRIVER (NameError)

Comment: Code i've tried :
    require 'watir-webdriver'
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'roo'
    Watir::always_locate = true   
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    profile.native_events = false
    b = Watir::Browser.new WEB_DRIVER, :profile => profile
and got Error As :
`<main>': uninitialized constant WEB_DRIVER (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "unable to locate element" error you're experiencing, if you're using Watir to manipulate the elements then I'd try applying ".wait_until_present" or ".when_present" to see if it's a case of that step in question executing too quickly. Hope that helps! Let us know!

Comment: Yes I used Whatever you have mentioned,whenever unable to identify object.But actually  my issue was while executing code first time it operates without any issue then next time it throws error.to avoid that i have included 
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new 
    profile.native_events = false 
    b = Watir::Browser.new WEB_DRIVER, :profile => profile

Answer (score 0):

```
Watir::always_locate = true   

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

profile.native_events = false

b=Watir::Browser.new:firefox, :profile => profile
```

This works for me